# WPF and control auto size

Tags: wpf

is it possible that if i put a textbox in border container and will not specify height & width of textbox rather specify height & width for border and textbox will take the size of the border. how could i do this. i tried to do it in xaml but fail. need answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment.stretch.aspx

Comment: This link is dead

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
   <Border Width="100" Height="100">
      <TextBox />
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

The text box will be of size of the border.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice and easy:

```
<Border Width="200" Height="70" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
  <TextBox></TextBox>
</Border>
```